# how to redirect from server side ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I have a code where I want after the user signs in to be redirected.
I've seen some posts here saying that this redirection needs to be the last operation, but still it is not working.

How can I redirect my user from server side?

```
def singIn
    params.require(:adm).permit(:login, :password)
    adm = Adm.where("login = ? and password = ?", params[:adm][:login], params[:adm][:password])

    if adm.count == 1
      session[:adm] = "true"
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    else
      session[:adm] = "false"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why `"true"` instead of `true`? Also, do you store unencrypted passwords in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` didn't have a redirect. Also, your `if` had a return after the redirect. You should use something like this:

```
def singIn
  params.require(:adm).permit(:login, :password)
  adm = Adm.where("login = ? and password = ?", params[:adm][:login], params[:adm][:password])

  if adm.count == 1
    session[:adm] = "true"
  else
    session[:adm] = "false"
  end

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

If you need two different redirects depending on something, just put them inside the if/else like so:

```
  if adm.count == 1
    session[:adm] = "true"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    session[:adm] = "false"
    redirect_to other_path
  end
```